# Clone div using Javascript and change inner DOM elements ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a two static div tags, inside that I have one select tag and one text box with different ID's. So when I clone the tag, it just adds the same div tag to the DOM, but how can I change the inner DOM elements tag?

Here is my code

```
        <div id="masterGrade" style="border-style: solid; width: 200px">
        <select id="selectGrade1">
            <option value="grade1">Grade 1</option>
            <option value="grade2">Grade 2</option>
            <option value="grade3">Grade 3</option>
            <option value="grade4">Grade 4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="text1"/>
    </div>
    <div style="border-style: solid;width: 200px">
        <select id="selectGrade2">
            <option value="grade1">Grade 1</option>
            <option value="grade2">Grade 2</option>
            <option value="grade3">Grade 3</option>
            <option value="grade4">Grade 4</option>
        </select>
        <input type="text" id="text2"/>
    </div>
```

My JS code

```
    $scope.addGrade = function() {  

        var div = document.getElementById('masterGrade'),
        clone = div.cloneNode(true); 
        clone.id = "some_id";
        document.body.appendChild(clone);
    }
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Mixing `DOM api` with `angular` is not a best practice. You must do it angular way(`ng-repeat`).. I never said it is impossible..

Comment: @RayonDabre, Can you plz post with your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixing `DOM api` with `angular` is not a *best practice*. You must do it angular way(`ng-repeat`)

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.grades = [{}];
  $scope.addGrade = function() {
    $scope.grades.push({});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <button ng-click='addGrade()'>Add</button>
  <div style="border-style: solid; width: 200px" ng-repeat='grade in grades'>
    <select ng-model='grade.list'>
      <option value="grade1">Grade 1</option>
      <option value="grade2">Grade 2</option>
      <option value="grade3">Grade 3</option>
      <option value="grade4">Grade 4</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" ng-model='grade.text' />
  </div>
  {{grades}}
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/od5c3jvb/)

**Edit**: To deal with the `index`, use [`$index`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat), *The `ngRepeat` directive instantiates a template once per item from a collection. Each template instance gets its own scope, where the given loop variable is set to the current collection item, and `$index` is set to the item index or key.*

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.grades = [{}];
  $scope.addGrade = function() {
    $scope.grades.push({});
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <button ng-click='addGrade()'>Add</button>
  <div style="border-style: solid; width: 200px" ng-repeat='grade in grades'>
    <label for="select{{$index}}">Grade {{$index}}:</label>
    <select id='select{{$index}}' ng-model='grade.list'>
      <option value="grade1">Grade 1</option>
      <option value="grade2">Grade 2</option>
      <option value="grade3">Grade 3</option>
      <option value="grade4">Grade 4</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <label for="text{{$index}}">Text{{$index}}:</label>
    <input id='text{{$index}}' type="text" ng-model='grade.text' size='10' />
  </div>
  {{grades}}
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/od5c3jvb/1/)

Comment: Rayon, I guess you didn't understand my question. The ng-model of select tag and textbox also should change. Initially there would be two div tags on load, so on clicking on "Add", it should start from 3rd div. Hope I have cleared the question properly.

Comment: The purpose of writing `{{grades}}` is to demonstrate that each `ng-repeat` has its own scope. Type values in the `text` to test! To have `2` divs initially.. just `$scope.grades = [{}, {}];`

Comment: grade.list is the ng-model you have defined. It should be like grade.list1 for first one, grade.list2 for the second one and so on..

Comment: Because, it will help me to distinguish from which tag I have recieved the value, instead of getting it by chain process

Comment: How will you differentiate that ? Using this approach, you still have the `$index` with you.. `data-index={{$index}}`

Comment: But that is my requirement Rayon.. :( If its possible can you plz update your answer with $index thing?

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rayon